# resultant from division (mod) behaves strange

Tags: c++

This should be a very basic stuff, but somehow i don't see the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int dim>
inline
void
i2c(const int & ind, int & i, int &j) {
        i = (int) ind / dim;
        j =       ind & dim;
        //j = ind - i*dim;
}

static const int dim = 2;

int main() {
    int i,j;

    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < dim*dim; c++) {
        i2c<dim>(c,i,j);
        std::cout<<c<<"/"<<dim<<"="<<i<<"; "<<c<<"&"<<dim<<"="<<j<<std::endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the [code](http://codepad.org/qmiE9fpo).

The output is:

```
0/2=0; 0&2=0
1/2=0; 1&2=0
2/2=1; 2&2=2
3/2=1; 3&2=2
```

If i use `j = ind - i*dim` - everything is ok.

**EDIT1**: 
can someone delete the question so that i'm not ashamed of being blind ? ;)

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Why are you doing bitwise AND ( `&` )? Name of question mentions modulus, which is `%`

Comment: @olevegard shit, that's true! overheated.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `j = ind & (dim - 1);`, assuming `dim` is a power of two.

That extracts lower-order bits, which has the effect of computing the modulo. Of course, most compilers will see this optimization coming from a mile away, so you really should just use the `%` operator to do modulo for real:

```
j = ind % mod;
```

Comment: Or, as apparent from the comments, `%` for modulo! ;) But it was what I was thinking too....